# Error using libavcodec with linux in C/C++

Tags: c++, libavcodec, libavformat, libav

The problem: AVFormatContext::nb_streams has too larve value.
My C++ code (error handling, includes etc. omited to reduce the listing):

```
void printA(AVFormatContext* _a)
{
std::cout << "duration    " << (unsigned long)_a->duration << "\n";
std::cout << "streams     " << _a->nb_streams << "\n";
std::cout << "format name " << _a->iformat->name << "\n";
std::cout << "bit_rate    " << _a->bit_rate << "\n";
std::cout << "long name   " << _a->iformat->long_name << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{


if ( argc < 2 )
{
    std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <file>\n";
    return 1;
}

    av_register_all();

AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();

avformat_open_input (&pFormatCtx, argv[1], NULL, NULL);
avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL);

printA( pFormatCtx );
return 0;
}
```

Running:

```
xx@xx /tmp/avlib $ ./avlibtest /ar/video/Nauka.Sna.2006.HDRip.AVC.mkv 
[matroska,webm @ 0x804c040] max_analyze_duration reached
[matroska,webm @ 0x804c040] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
duration    134741408
streams     134531840     <---- !!! :-O
format name matroska,webm
bit_rate    0
long name   Matroska/WebM file format
```

But the "avplay" program works well.

Comment: have you looked at this variable in the debuger window? This could also be a type conversion error on behalf of std::cout and I am probably wrong

Comment: It is unsigned int, so i don't see any issue here.

Comment: have you tried iterating through actual streams pointer?

Comment: `duration` value `134741408` (`0x807FDA0`) and `streams` value `134531840` (`0x804CB00`) both look like memory addresses instead of actual values. (Nice movie, by the way :))